# How to call python nose test cases in c#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have to run the python nose testcases and have to call the individual test scripts ,which is in the python nose testcase and display the result in windows form
Is there is any API or run time engine is available in c# or any alternate way to achieve this

Comment: You tagged the question IronPython, doesn't that pretty much answer the question? If you tried to use IronPython and failed, can you describe how exactly did it fail?

Comment: I got syntax error while calling engine.Execute() function. But same script is working fine while running with python nose

Comment: Then you might want to ask a specific question about that, including your C# and Python code. As a first guess: could it be due to the difference between Python 2 and Python 3?

Comment: Iron python code snippet ScriptEngine pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
            dynamic output = pyEngine.Execute(@"F:\Python\Examples\test_DateFormat.py");

Comment: Python Test case:                                                                            import unittest
from datetime import date

class TimeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_isoformat(self):
        t = date(2014, 5, 2)

        self.assertEqual(t.isoformat(), "2014-05-02")